# having a CSSStyleDeclaration object can I find what node it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, css

I mean the reverse of this function:

```
styleObj = window.getComputedStyle(node);
```

So something like this:

```
node = window.getNodeFromStyle(styleObj);
```

Comment: It's possible. You could traverse all nodes and check if the styles match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

A CSSStyleDeclaration is just some style rules, they could be attached to any element.